# Configuring Dependabot/Renovate: Seeking Assistance with Specific Settings

Tags: security, dependency-management, dependabot, renovate

I have a question: will Dependabot or Renovate help us if an SCA (BlackDuck) tool finds vulnerabilities, and will they only fix those vulnerabilities identified by the SCA tool?

I have gone through the documentation for both Dependabot and Renovate, but I am unable to find any information related to this

Comment: If there's no doc, it likely means it's not possible :)

Comment: Renovate doesn't support this AFAIK. It will open MR/PR for all available upgrades. It can flag some of they are related to known vulnerabilities. But it works standalone, it won't accept input from another tool to do its work if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Consider their GitHub discussions for such questions btw :)

Comment: Thank you for your response to my question. I will check the GitHub discussion. :)